# catching an exception thrown by a statement in servlet stops the execution(no output is displayed)

Tags: java

public class upload extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
    {

        String img=request.getParameter("upload");

        Blob image=new SerialBlob(img.getBytes());

        HttpSession hs=request.getSession();

        int id=(Integer) hs.getAttribute("id");
        out.println("id "+id);
        int status=Dao.upload(image,id);

    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
}
```

//here i am using a the Blob datatype to getbytes of an image to store it in database, and this statement throws SQLException, for which i have written catch block.
now this catch block is stopping the program to print the "id"(print statement is not working).

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}
 these are my doGet() and doPost() methods.

Comment: The exception is thrown before `println`, and the exception is swallowed so there is no output.  In the catch block, consider adding: `out.println("processing error");`.

Comment: Comment `out.println("id "+id);` and try.. if still the error persists type `ex.printStackTrace()` in the catch block and post that stacktrace here